# How to Change Weights Dynamically in a Simple Function?

Tags: statistics, functions, optimization, dynamical-systems

So I have what I think is a pretty basic task in math conceptually, but even trying to describe it is eluding me, so please bear with me. I have a basic weighted equation:
$$a*x_1 + b*x_2 \ + ... + \ j*x_{10} \ ,$$
with
$$a + b \ + ... + \ j = 1 \ ,$$
and the basic weights are all figured out already (for ex., a = .733 and b = -.12).

So what I want to do is alter the weights **dynamically**, based on some subjective criterion. So let's say I have 10 new subjective weights, 
$$a_1 + a_2 \ + ... + \ a_{10} = 1\ ,$$
that I want to use to alter the previous weights, such that each previous weight will **increase** or **decrease** based on each corresponding new weight.

For example, if a = .733, b = -.12, and a1 = .2, a2 = -.1, a will increase and b will decrease proportionately. The difficulty lies with calculating these proportional increases and decreases for all the original weights and at the same time, while still respecting the condition
$$a + b \ + ... + \ j = 1 \ .$$

Does anybody know what I'm trying to do? For reference, what my problem is is altering the weights of different stocks in a portfolio based on some new info, like company a reporting good financials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what you gave us, I would do the following:

(I am assuming $a,b,\cdots, j$ are the parameters you want to adjust and I am assuming the $a_i$ reflect how much you want to change the $i$th letter)

First, take

$$\begin{cases}
a' = a_1\times a\\
b' = a_2\times b\\
\cdots \\
j' = a_{10}\times j\end{cases}$$

This made the parameters $a,\cdots,j$ change proportionately. Now we need re-ensure their sum is $1$; take

$$S = a' + b' + \cdots + j'$$

And then set

$$\begin{cases}
a'' = \frac{a'}{S}\\
b'' = \frac{b'}{S}\\
\cdots \\
j'' = \frac{j'}{S}\end{cases}$$

Now you have your new parameters with $a'' + b'' + \cdots + j'' = 1$.

Is that good enough for you?

Comment: I am going to work through your answer right now and see if the results make sense to me. I just realized right now that a better condition for the new subjective weights is to = 10, because 1*n (with n being 10) is 10. 
So I will change a1 = 1.2 and a2 = .9 .

Comment: I did what you said, with a minor change as described above, and the final weights do not add up to 1.
https://imgur.com/a/SBdG3

Comment: You are not supposed to divide by $10$. You divide by the value *sum* in the third column. For your image, you would divide by $0.12...$.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful question and comment, as normalization has never been something I had to do before. I understood your answer and it helped calculate my new portfolio.